# Tap event does not work in Chrome running under Android 4.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile tap events do not appear to be firing in Chrome running under Android 4.0.4.  The tap events do fire if the standard Android browser is used instead of Chrome.  Can anyone tell me why Chrome is not detecting the tap events and is there a known work-around to capture tap events accurately in Android Chrome?

Comment: Can you say "tap events" a few more times?  I didn't quite catch that :p

Comment: Try `vclick` event instead of `tap`.

Comment: vclick did indeed work.  I can use in place of the tap event to accomplish the same thing.  I have a similar issue with jquery mobile swipe left and swipe right events not working in Chrome running under Android 4.0.4. Do you have a solution for that also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given by Omar above.  Using the vclick event instead of the tap event works on all devices and browsers I have tested it on so far, so this is a good solution.

Comment: What should we use instead of "doubletap"?